# Angular, Django undefined value from Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a get_context_data in my view

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    humans = Human.objects.all()
    context['humans'] = [{'fname': i.first_name, 'lname':i.last_name} for i in humans]
    return context
```

When I have this:

```
{% for human in humans %}
<tr>
    <td>{{human.fname}} {{human.lname}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine. I get
John Doe
Michael Smith
etc...

but, when I've tried put this values to angulary by:

```
{%verbatim%}
...
<button ng-controller="MyCtrl" type="submit" ng-click="
    {%endverbatim%}
    myFunc({{human.fname}},{{human.lname}})
    {%verbatim%}">
Send
</button> 
...
{%endverbatim%}
```

I've got only undefined:

```
#in my controller:
#...
$scope.myFunc = function(fname, lname){
    $log.log(fname, lname); // <- this returns 2x undefined
}
```

Guys, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Django verbatim looks like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

You have the `{% endverbatim %}` tag before `{% verbatim %}` in your snippet.

```
<button ng-controller="MyCtrl" type="submit" ng-click="
    {%endverbatim%}
    myFunc({{human.fname}},{{human.lname}})
    {%verbatim%}">
Send
</button>
```

Comment: I don't get in. About the verbatim tags, I've updated my code. endverbatim on django tags, verbatim off, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it

```
myFunc("{{human.fname}}","{{human.lname}}")
```

instead

```
myFunc({{human.fname}},{{human.lname}})
```